# Recommend of English video about math

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, math-software

My mother tongue is not English, but sometime there are some math reports or conference using English .Because my English is poor, I can't  understand it well and can't suitably describe my question. So, I want to watch math video using English to  improve my English . Which web there are video course with **English subtitles**. If it is about *Riemann geometry*, it is better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These all have english subtitles and are are highly enjoyable:

[Discrete Mathematics. Arsdigita University. Instructor: Shai Simonson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_9WjWENWV8&list=PL3o9D4Dl2FJ9q0_gtFXPh_H4POI5dK0yG)

[The Fourier Transforms and its Applications. Standford. Professor Brad Osgood](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZNm7L96pfY&list=PLB24BC7956EE040CD)

[Probability. Harvard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KbB0FjPg0mw&list=PL2SOU6wwxB0uwwH80KTQ6ht66KWxbzTIo)

[Probability Primer. Mathematicalmonk's channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tk4ubu7BlSk&list=PL17567A1A3F5DB5E4)

[General topology from the very basics, including set theory, techniques for proofs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivO9_O0YSSc&list=PLpG_ISEhQ6z0Q5MaIvdn5tBJFWfp9fZtQ)

[Graph theory by Sarada Herke](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIb1cz06UwI&list=PLoJC20gNfC2gmT_5WgwYwGMvgCjYVsIQg)

[Short course on writing proofs in mathematics by Sidney Morris](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1snRQEQuEk)